How to retrieve the front door id from a Microsoft CDN (classic)
I have created a Microsoft CDN (classic) in Azure and I need to retrieve the value of the X-Azure-Fdid.
This value is not displayed in the Microsoft Azure Portal nor it is returned in the Azure CLI reponse.
Portal:

Azure CLI:
az cdn profile list --resource-group redacted --output json
{
    "extendedProperties": {},
    "id": "/subscriptions/redacted/resourcegroups/redacted/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/testtest",
    "kind": "cdn",
    "location": "Global",
    "name": "testtest",
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "resourceGroup": "redacted",
    "resourceState": "Active",
    "sku": {
      "name": "Standard_Microsoft"
    },
    "tags": {},
    "type": "Microsoft.Cdn/profiles"
  }

az cdn endpoint list --profile-name testtest --resource-group op-1 --output json
[
  {
    "contentTypesToCompress": [
      "application/eot",
      "application/font",
      "application/font-sfnt",
      "application/javascript",
      "application/json",
      "application/opentype",
      "application/otf",
      "application/pkcs7-mime",
      "application/truetype",
      "application/ttf",
      "application/vnd.ms-fontobject",
      "application/xhtml+xml",
      "application/xml",
      "application/xml+rss",
      "application/x-font-opentype",
      "application/x-font-truetype",
      "application/x-font-ttf",
      "application/x-httpd-cgi",
      "application/x-javascript",
      "application/x-mpegurl",
      "application/x-opentype",
      "application/x-otf",
      "application/x-perl",
      "application/x-ttf",
      "font/eot",
      "font/ttf",
      "font/otf",
      "font/opentype",
      "image/svg+xml",
      "text/css",
      "text/csv",
      "text/html",
      "text/javascript",
      "text/js",
      "text/plain",
      "text/richtext",
      "text/tab-separated-values",
      "text/xml",
      "text/x-script",
      "text/x-component",
      "text/x-java-source"
    ],
    "customDomains": [],
    "geoFilters": [],
    "hostName": "testtesttest.azureedge.net",
    "id": "/redacted/resourcegroups/redacted/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/testtest/endpoints/testtesttest",
    "isCompressionEnabled": true,
    "isHttpAllowed": true,
    "isHttpsAllowed": true,
    "location": "Global",
    "name": "testtesttest",
    "originGroups": [],
    "originHostHeader": "test.com",
    "origins": [
      {
        "enabled": true,
        "hostName": "test.com",
        "httpPort": 80,
        "httpsPort": 443,
        "name": "test-com",
        "originHostHeader": "test.com",
        "priority": 1,
        "weight": 1000
      }
    ],
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "queryStringCachingBehavior": "BypassCaching",
    "resourceGroup": "redacted",
    "resourceState": "Running",
    "tags": {},
    "type": "Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints"
  }
]

The only way I was able to retrieve this ID so far was to look at the access logs on my origin server which is not ideal...
If this helps I created the CDN using Terraform and the following resource:
resource "azurerm_cdn_profile" "example" {
  name                = var.cdn_profile_name
  location            = "West Europe"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "Standard_Microsoft"
}

Note:
It appears that it is currently not possible to create an a Premium_AzureFrontDoor CDN using Terraform at the moment (see this GitHub issue: azurerm_cdn_profile SKU is not up to date).

As of today there does not appear to be a way to a classic Microsoft CDN's XAzureFDID value outside the logs.  I can confirm that the CDN does in fact have an assigned XAzureFDID.
I have a web app origin that is served both by a premium Front Door instance and a classic Microsoft CDN.  When I look at the AppServiceIPSecAuditLogs I see the XAzureFDID column populated with a Front Door ID for all calls originating from Front Door.  I also see a separate XAzureFDID for the calls originating from the Microsoft CDN.
In the logs for calls from Front Door:

In the logs for calls from the CDN:  
Under the Microsoft.Cdn/profiles properties for the Front Door instance, via resources.azure.com:

Under the Microsoft.Cdn/profiles properties for the classic CDN:


The sku "Premium_AzureFrontDoor" corresponds to the "Azure CDN Premium from Edgio" in the Azure Portal UI right ?

No, the sku for "Azure CDN Premium from Edgio" is actually "Premium_Verizon".  There are several ways to verify but you can go to resources.azure.com and search for the name of your resource in the search box, click the resource, and it'll take you to your resource's properties.

Here's a comparison between Azure Front Door and the Azure CDNs:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-cdn-comparison

To retrieve frontdoorId (X-Azure-Fdid), you can use following commands:
$afd = az network front-door show --name "your_frontdoor_name" --resource-group "frontdoor_resource_group_name"

$convertedafd = $afd | ConvertFrom-Json

for X-Azure-Fdid -->
$convertedafd.frontdoorId

Documentation for the frontdoor az cli - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/front-door?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-front-door-show

This command is for Classical Azure Front Doors which I'm not using.

How did you get x-fdid for cdn one from portal?
